# grouping tracks in Logic 9

Tags: logic, group

i'm still quite disappointed with the rather archaic way of grouping tracks in logic. with grouping i mean the ability to collect a number of tracks into a group or a single track, and control all contained tracks at once, in order to keep in the arrangement window clean and tidy. i know of the Folders feature in logic, but i never really got used to working with it. i'm curious how do logic users here approach this issue? ... when using the Folders feature, is it even possible to assign an effect / process all tracks in the folder without creating an additional aux channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you mean, archaic way of grouping tracks? PT and other DAW-s has the same feature set also as Logic.
As far as I know, folder tracks, only offers better grouping and handling of tracks, and house cleaning work, and also recording workflow and group editing features, but no inserts for them without addition aux bus-es. 
There is a great tutorial on MacProVideo with folder workflow, from SFLogicNinja:
http://www.macprovideo.com/tutorial/logic407

My workflow for grouping, contains submixes of instrument groups, or audio tracks grouping. And If I need automation on Aux buses, I simply creata an Arrangement track to those buses, and working with them as audio tracks as far as inserts, sends and automation. If fx printing needed to those busses, simply recording them to an audio track.
Additionally, you can hide audio tracks for the group, if the space and clean arrangement is needed, and create arrangement track for the group as I mentioned earlier.